# Dots in URLs replaced by underscore

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a little problem on Apache with Rewrite on.
My rewrite is like that (for an old CodeIgniter) :

```
RewriteCond $1 !(index\.php|index\.html)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1%{QUERY_STRING} [QSA]
```

if I pass this kind of URL :

```
http://server.fr/seg1/seg2/email/aaa@bbb.fr/other/1.3
```

And if I log the $_GET vars at the beginning of my index.php, I have this:

```
array(2) {
  ["email"]=>
  string(10) "aaa@bbb_fr"
  ["other"]=>
  string(3) "1_3"
}
```

Don't understand why all dots are replaced...
Any ideas welcome !

Thanks

Comment: PHP does it by design. http://us2.php.net/variables.external

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking, the dots are invalid chars. and are converted to underscores. @AnthonySterling

Comment: @AnthonySterling - In parameter **names**, not values :-?

Comment: Dots are allowed by the RFC spec in names, unencoded. This is a design bug in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
$config['uri_protocol']  = 'AUTO';
```

... to ...

```
$config['uri_protocol']  = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

in config.php file.